# Laravel using a model in a custom class

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a custom class, which is a Facade. Here is the class:

```
<?php namespace MT\Library;

class Posting
{
    function Draft($inputs)
    {
        return ($this->create($inputs, 0)) ? true : false;
    }

    private function create ($inputs, $type)
    {
        $post = new Illuminate\Database\Post();
        $post->title = $inputs["title"];

        return ($post->save()) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

`Posting()` is the name of my custom class.

```
Post()
```

is the name of my Laravel Eloquent Model. When I use the class `Postin::Draft()` it throws an error that cannot find the model `new Illuminate\Database\Post();`

How should I use my model in my custom library? Since my library uses a namespace I cannot simply do `Post()` for model, as it throws an error telling cannot find `Post()`

Comment: Could you try using $post = new \Illuminate\Database\Post(); and check as to what the result is?

Answer (score 2):

If it is in the `models` folder then use:

```
$post = new \Post();
```

Also you may add `use Post` at the top of your class.

Whenever using a class from another `namespace` use `\` before the class name (including namespace if exists) you are referring; to indicate that, it's in the global namespace, otherwise `PHP` will look under the current `namespace`.